# Smooth rotary incremental encoders?

Tags: potentiometer

Do rotary incremental encoders exist that have the smooth feeling, as if turning a  potentiometer? If so, does this have a name, how to identify these?

I love the flexibility of encoders in my designs, but I don't like the clunky feeling. Disclaimer: my experience is limited to two cheap encoders of Aliexpress ;-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The clicks are called [Detents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detent). You are looking for encoders with 0 detent points, the [Alps EC12E2430404](https://www.alps.com/prod/info/E/HTML/Encoder/Incremental/EC12E/EC12E2430404.html) is one example.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of the blue and metal 20-position rotary encoders widely available from Chinese resellers, you can actually convert the detented versions into non-detented versions.

Use needle-nose pliers to squeeze together each of the four split retaining clips (two on each side) holding the bottom and top halves together. Remove the top (metal-only) half. Use tweezers to remove the flat metal spring from that half and the tiny metal ball-bearing which creates the detent. Fit the two halves back together, re-spreading the retaining clips. And bingo, you've removed the detent-ness.

Answer (score 2):

Digikey has a whole range of detent-less rotary encoders

https://www.digikey.com/products/en/sensors-transducers/encoders/507?k=rotary+encoder&k=&pkeyword=rotary+encoder&pv1989=0&pv394=2&FV=ffe001fb&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25